# wkhtmltopdf image generation is slow on some pcs

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf

In a C# application, I am using the  NReco.ImageGenerator library which encapsulates the wkhtmltopdf library to convert html to images. While on my reasonably powerful pc (i7, 8gb ram, non-ssd, Windows 7 64bit), the speed is good (1 second max per picture?), on other pcs the whole operation can take from 20 to 40 seconds for 1 picture.

One of those pcs is another developer pc, just like mine with slightly better cpu. Running it through the Visual Studio debugger, the whole delay is caused on the following lines:

```
 var htmlToImageConv = new NReco.ImageGenerator.HtmlToImageConverter();
 var jpegBytes = htmlToImageConv.GenerateImage(html, ImageFormat.Png);
```

Any idea what might be slowing it down or what can I do it debug it/improve the speed?

Comment: If you download the command line tool from http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html and run it on the same input is it any faster?

Comment: Sadly no, it actually seems to be going fast only on my pc. On just about every other pc it takes 20-40 secs

Comment: Would be able to post the HTML with its resources, you are converting? Otherwise to note is that if you have external resources on other servers please note, that these will be downloaded for rendering. So different connection types might also contribute to different conversion times.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. The html loads a .jpg from a url and while the jpg is small, it looks like some pcs have issues with it (granted they are all within the same company network...can't remember if I had ask IT to open some ports for mine). When I changed the .jpg url to a local file .jpg, the image was rendered properly in 1 second. If you make a normal reply, I could mark it as answer!

Answer (score 2):

When using wkhtmltopdf to convert HTML to a PDF or an image note that external resources on other servers will be downloaded for rendering. 
The downloading of these resources (e.g. images, fonts, css, javascript) will have an impact on the time it takes to do the conversion.